# ThreeJS Modularity - Separating Three from html

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to make my little app a little more modular.  It would be awesome if I could move all of the Three stuff out of the html page, and into its own js file.

Included "import * as THREE from 'three'" at the top of my JS, but couldn't figure out how to avoid "Cannot use import statement outside a module."  Went with this: "let THREE=  import("../build/three.module.js") " at the top of the module, which didn't give me the same error, but now it doesn't recognize "THREE".

Struggling through a number of different google searches, but haven't found what I'm looking for..

This was interesting: [here](https://pierfrancesco-soffritti.medium.com/how-to-organize-the-structure-of-a-three-js-project-77649f58fa3f) but I either didn't understand it, or it didn't help me get where I needed to be.

Thoughts?  Anything is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looked harder, and found a couple of solutions.  Posting links here.

[Link 1 - Webpack Solution](https://sbcode.net/threejs/webpack-dev-server/)
[Link 2 - Webpack Solution](https://threejs-journey.com/lessons/webpack#more-about-the-webpack-template)

Both are pretty good tutorials meant for someone going through this for the first time.  (Like me.)  One or both require payment at some point for the more in-depth topics.  But - there are solutions for the problem above that are accessible for free.

Good luck.